# how to scale splashcreen image in Java ME application created in Netbeans

Tags: java, image, netbeans, java-me, splash-screen

I create Java ME application in Netbeans. I use a splashcreen and I put an image on it. I want this image to be scaled, so it has a right size on different screens - bigger ones and smaller ones. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly there is a method that you can call that will get the height and width of the screen that is currently in use. You can then use these values to re-size you image as needed. Here is an example of getting the height and width:

http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/how-to-get-the-size-of-mobile-screen.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

there is no image prossing api in midp 2.0 spec. so you should use 3rd library of function. you can use lwuit library. it has many image process functionality.

http://lwuit.java.net/

Answer (score 0):

This is Simple One Example to show you [Splash Screen in JavaME](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/SplashScreen_Full_Screen)
Thanks